# How to copy paste multimedia components from one publication to the other publication using Tridion core service API?

Tags: 2011, core-service

How to copy paste multimedia components from one publication to the other publication using SDL Tridion core service API ?

We have multimedia components which have to be copied to another publication. unable to assign image to the new component in new publication from old one.

Comment: Hi Shreshtha - did you get a solution to this? Please do share...

Answer (score 3):

Just like using the Tridon CM gui can't copy content across publications, you can't copy content using a core service function.
You can off course do the following

- read the component you wish to copy from publication A
- create a new component in publication B
- copy all data from the original component into the newly created component.

You will have to pay attention with file names. If publication B is a child of publication A (or the other way around), you will get an error if you try to create a component with the same name in the same folder. If both publications are **not** in the same Blueprint chain than naming conflicts may be less likely but are something your architecture must account for.

A question similar to yours has already been answered, you can find some useful code samples here
https://tridion.stackexchange.com/a/1105/242

Answer (score 3):

Shreshtha - as you see - you cannot do this through the GUI but it is possible via the **Core Service** as mentioned by Harald.

If this is a one-off you could consider using **Content Porter** or, as you've mentioned this is Multimedia items, you could copy and paste these via **WebDAV** and the appropriate cartridges (see the post from Alvin here http://www.createandbreak.net/2012/12/webdav-is-fast-upload-multimedia-is.html for some useful information).

In all cases - the Blueprint chain *must* be considered and naming conflicts etc. avoided.