# How to move google sitemap.xml created using core service from CMS server to CD server?

Tags: 2013-sp1, core-service

I want to create tridion core service application to create google sitemap.xml file. My CMS server is windows server and CD server is linux server.Is it possible to push sitemap.xml from CMS server to CDA server ? If yes, please suggest how can we do it ?

Comment: Am I missing something? Right-click, publish?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest to use the regular tridion publish functionality for this.
A more simple approach would be to use a template building block to generate the sitemap xml, in that case, you could simply use this tbb to publish a certain page.
There is an example of similar functionality here
http://www.tridiondeveloper.com/web-sitemap

If you really need to use core services, then I suggest to use the following approach

- generate the sitemap.xml from core services
- use the generated xml to update a multimedia component, that holds the xml file (this can also be done using core services - example code can be found here : [Creating Binary Components using the Core Service](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/1103/creating-binary-components-using-the-core-service))
- finally, send a publish command from core services (example : http://blog.building-blocks.com/technical-tips/publishing-components-using-the-core-service-in-sdl-tridion-2011)

So, while both options are viable, but unless you have some specific requirement to use the core services, I suggest to use the first option, and create the sitemap XML using a template building block, as this is the most straight-forward way of achieving what you want.

Comment: Hi Harald,Thanks for providing the different approaches. I need to use core services as all our sitemap files for different regions are published in one common "sitemaps" folder.For this activity I will be required to access different publications. That was the reason I was thinking of using core services. Can we achieve similar functionality using C#TBB ?